# .Net Core 2.0 Identity Framework Custom Role Injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-identity

I just want to apply my custom implementations to base IdentityUser and IdentityRole.

Here is my role

```
public class CcrRole : IdentityRole<int>
{
}
```

Here is my custom user implementation

```
public class CcrUser : IdentityUser<int>
{
    public EntityStatus EntityStatus { get; set; }
    public string AvatarPath { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

And here is my DbContext:

```
public class CcrDbContext : IdentityDbContext<CcrUser, CcrRole, int>
{
    public CcrDbContext(DbContextOptions options)
      : base(options)
    {

    }
    public DbSet<AnnualPermit> AnnualPermits { get; set; }
}
```

When i run this Here is my ConfigureServices method. I just want to define that my role is  CcrRole. Not IdentityRole.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContextPool<CcrDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("AppDbConnection")));
        services
            .AddIdentity<CcrUser, CcrRole>(t =>
            {
                t.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            })
            .AddRoles<CcrRole>()
            .AddUserStore<CcrUserStore>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
    }
```

The error it gives me is:
[image]

Apparently it tries to cast the CcrRole into IRoleStore. But it is not a store. I don't know why does it expect RoleStore on AddRoles method.
Any idea why? Thanx.

## edit:

i want to inject the user store to my controllers. But while doing that i dont want to pass all thoose generic types. I just want to use my CustomUserStore which CcrUserStore in this case. When i type thoose generics i can run the application but when i want to inject my custom userstore it gives me the errow abow.

here is my controller:
[image]

and my Custom UserStore:
[image]

Comment: Why can you use RoleStore<CcrRole> from DI? This should get you your role what you want

Comment: Which line is causing the problem - is it the `.AddRoles` or `AddUserStore`? Does using the long form of `AddUserStore` help? e.g.  `.AddUserStore<UserStore<CcrUser, CcrRole, CcrDbContext, int>>()`

Comment: Try `.AddEntityFrameworkStores<CcrDbContext>()` in place of `.AddRoles()` and `.AddUserStore()`.

Comment: @kalit; i explained on edit why i don't want it. 
@CalC; also explained it on edit. it works but the controller i made the injection gives the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to reproduce the same problem that you have encountered. 
However, I believe a significant root cause of the problem may be that the `AddUserStore` method has a generic type argument which is the `User` type, not the type of the `UserStore` (see [IdentityBuilder in the Github repo for rel 2.0](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/release/2.0/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core/IdentityBuilder.cs#L108)). As of 2.1, this extension has changed to accept a UserStore as a type argument. Therefore, if you want/need to add your own `UserStore`, you could set up the DI as follows:

```
services
    .AddIdentity<CcrUser, CcrRole>(t =>
    {
        t.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
    })
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

services.AddScoped<IUserStore<CcrUser>, CcrUserStore>();
```

You would then need to change the signature of the `AnnualPermitController` constructor as follows:

```
public AnnualPermitController(CcrDbContext context, IUserStore<CcrUser> userStore)
  : base(options)
{
    //...
}
```

However, despite the above, I believe creating custom UserStores is quite rare. You would probably want a very specific and important requirement in order to want to go down the road of creating your own `UserStore`.

Comment: yeah tried this, but like i said when i want to inject my custom store still same error. probably it will work if i try to inject the generic version ...But i don't want it. 
But the thing is why is it trying to cast or convert that role to store?

Comment: @ArgeKumandan Can you add the code for your `CcrUserStore` (and role store if it exists) to the question? It may help.

Comment: it's added to the question. Thanx for your interest. I stil did not solve the problem